# How to add HttpErrorResponse object to GET mock call in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am testing an interceptor in angular. Everything is OK apart adding the **HttpErrorResponse** object error.errorType parameter into my mocked request.

Here is the code:

```
it('should call showError method', () => {

    httpClient.get('url').subscribe(
      result => {},
      (err) => {
        expect(timeoutService.showError).toHaveBeenCalled();
      }
    );

    const request = httpMock.expectOne('url');
    request.error(new ErrorEvent('TIMEOUT'), {
      status: 500,
      statusText: 'Internal Server Error'
    });

  });
```

I need to add the following into my test

```
 const httpErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({});
    httpErrorResponse.error.errorType = 'TIMEOUT';
```

Because I have it in my if statement inside my interceptor, If I remove the errorType check in my statement the passes of-course.

How can I add the extra parameter/object to my mocked request?

The docs say that I should have access to the HttpErrorResponse object but I'm not able to reach it. https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/TestRequest#description

**EDIT**

Looking at it more, I see that the property is read-only... Therefore the above httpErrorResponse and adding the parameter to it is wrong.

I think this can not be done in any way. Because errorType:'TIMEOUT' will always be that way for error 500, therefore checking inside my code for it is completely useless.

Comment: Can you add your interceptor code please?